# Why do some posts seem faded out suddenly?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

I just noticed, in the past day or so, that some posts appear to be faded out. As  DeAndre Cole would ask, "what up with that?"

> [image]

Comment: You've added a tag to your ignored tags list. At least one of `html`, `fancybox` or `title` is on that list.

Comment: I must have clicked something accidentally. I'll go find it :-/

Comment: Related... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've added one or more of `title`, `fancybox` or `hmtl` to your 'ignored tags' list.

Posts that have an ignored tag are displayed faded out. For posts that have both favourite and ignored tags, the post is displayed faded out with yellow background.